# Google Cloud Storage : PUT Object vs POST Object to upload file.?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Can any one please explain me what is main difference between PUT Object vs POST Object to upload file.

What are advantages and disadvantages of using each ??

Thanks.

Comment: that should be same as the difference between Http PUT and POST. Essentially these are some REST Api's provided to users for data/object etc storage. I worked on one at Y!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PUT vs POST in REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` if you cannot set the `Authorization` header -- generally because you are [uploading with an HTML form](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject).

Use `PUT` for [everything else](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#putobject).