# How to pass Service OAuth access_token from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-js-client

I am working on an application that is using Google Cloud Storage. I would like to use the JSON_API to manage uploading/downloading the pictures our user's provide. My goal is to grab the access_token using my service account method, and pass it off the the JSON_API JavaScript client api.

Here's my fancy pants class to grab the access_token:

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_StorageService.php';

class Model_Storage_Auth
{
    const CLIENT_ID = "clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountname@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    const KEY_FILE = "/super/secret/path/key.p12";
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';
    const APP_NAME = 'Fancy App';

    private $google_client;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->google_client = new Google_Client();
        $this->google_client->setApplicationName(self::APP_NAME);
    }

    public function getToken()
    {
        //return '{}';
        if(is_null($this->google_client->getAccessToken()))
        {
            try{$this->google_client->setAccessToken(Session::get(self::ACCESS_TOKEN, '{}'));}catch(Exception $e){}
            if(is_null($this->google_client->getAccessToken()))
            {
                $scope = array();
                $scope[] = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control';
                $key = file_get_contents(self::KEY_FILE);
                $this->google_client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                    self::SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    $scope,
                    $key)
                );
                $this->google_client->setClientId(self::CLIENT_ID);
                Google_Client::$auth->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
                $token = $this->google_client->getAccessToken();
                Session::set(self::ACCESS_TOKEN, $token);
            }
        }
        return $this->google_client->getAccessToken();
    }

}
```

I took the google JavaScript example and modified it a little bit to try to add my implementation, here it is:

```
<?php
$access_token = json_decode(html_entity_decode($access_token), true);
?>

<!--
  Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  the License.

  To run this sample, replace YOUR_API_KEY with your application's API key.
  It can be found at https://code.google.com/apis/console under API
  Access. Activate the Google Cloud Storage service at
  https://code.google.com/apis/console/ under Services
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /**
     * The number of your Google Cloud Storage Project.
     */
    var projectNumber = 'HAS REAL NUMBER IN MINE';

    /**
     * Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google Developer
     * Console. In your Developer Console project, add a JavaScript origin
     * that corresponds to the domain from where you will be running the
     * script.
     */
    var clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';

    /**
     * Enter the API key from the Google Developer Console, by following these
     * steps:
     * 1) Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=storage
     * 2) Click on "API Access" in the left column
     * 3) Find section "Simple API Access" and use the "API key." If sample is
     * being run on localhost then delete all "Referers" and save. Setting 
     * should display "Any referer allowed."
     */
    var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

    /**
     * To enter one or more authentication scopes, refer to the documentation
     * for the API.
     */
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control';

    /**
     * Constants for request parameters. Fill these values in with your custom
     * information.
     */
    var API_VERSION = 'v1beta1';
    var PROJECT = projectNumber;

    /**
     * The name of the new bucket to create.
     */
    var BUCKET = 'code-sample-bucket';

    /**
     * The name of the object inserted via insertObject method.  
     */
    var object = "";

    /**
     * Get this value from the API console.
     */
    var GROUP = 
    'group-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';

    /**
     * Valid values are user-userId, user-email, group-groupId, group-email,
     * allUsers, allAuthenticatedUsers
     */
    var ENTITY = 'allUsers';

    /**
     * Valid values are READER, OWNER
     */
    var ROLE = 'READER';

    /**
     * Valid values are READER, OWNER
     */
    var ROLE_OBJECT = 'READER';

    /**
     * A list of example calls to the Google Cloud Storage JavaScript client
     * library, as well as associated explanations of each call.
     */
    var listApiRequestExplanations = {
      'listBuckets': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
        'for a list of buckets in your project, and returns the result as ' +
        'a list of Google Cloud Storage buckets.',

      'listObjects': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
        'for a list of objects in your bucket, and returns the result as ' +
        'a list of Google Cloud Storage objects.',

      'listBucketsAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API for the list of access control lists on buckets in your ' +
        'project and returns the result as a list of Google Cloud Storage ' +
        'Access Control Lists.',

      'listObjectsAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API for the list of access control lists on objects in your ' +
        'bucket and returns the result as a list of Google Cloud Storage ' +
        'Access Control Lists.',

      'getBucket': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
        'for a bucket in your project, and returns the result as a ' +
        'Google Cloud Storage bucket.',

      'getBucketAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API for the access control list on a specific bucket ' +
        'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',

      'getObjectAccessControls': 'This API call queries the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API for the access control list on a specific object ' +
        'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',

      'insertBucket': 'This API call uses the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
        'to insert a bucket into your project.',

      'insertObject': 'This API call uses the Google Cloud Storage API ' +
        'to insert an object into your bucket.',

      'insertBucketAccessControls': 'This API uses the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API to insert an access control list on a specific bucket ' +
        'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',

      'insertObjectAccessControls': 'This API uses the Google Cloud ' +
        'Storage API to insert an access control list on a specific object ' +
        'and returns the result as a Google Cloud Storage Access Control List.',

      'deleteBucket': 'This API uses the Google Cloud Storage API to delete ' +
        'an empty bucket and returns an empty response to indicate success.',

      'deleteObject': 'This API uses the Google Cloud Storage API to delete ' +
        'an object and returns an empty response to indicate success.'
    };

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of buckets in
     * your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function listBuckets() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.list({
        'projectId': PROJECT
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'listBuckets');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the list of objects in
     * your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function listObjects() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.objects.list({
        'bucket': BUCKET
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'listObjects');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the access control list on
     * a bucket in your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function listBucketsAccessControls() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.list({
          'bucket': BUCKET
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'listBucketsAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve the access control list on
     * an object in your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function listObjectsAccessControls() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.list({
          'bucket': BUCKET,
          'object': object
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'listObjectsAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve a bucket in
     * your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function getBucket() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.get({
        'bucket': BUCKET
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'getBucket');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve a bucket's Access Control
     * List in your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function getBucketAccessControls() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.get({
        'bucket': BUCKET,
        'entity': GROUP
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'getBucketAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to retrieve an object's Access Control
     * List in your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function getObjectAccessControls() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.get({
        'bucket': BUCKET,
        'object': object,
        'entity': GROUP
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'getObjectAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert a bucket into
     * your Google Cloud Storage project.
     */
    function insertBucket() {
      resource = {
        'id': BUCKET,
        'projectId': PROJECT
      };

      var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.insert({
          'resource': resource
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'insertBucket');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an object into
     * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
     */
    function insertObject(event) {
      try{
        var fileData = event.target.files[0];
      } 
      catch(e) {
        //'Insert Object' selected from the API Commands select list
        //Display insert object button and then exit function
        filePicker.style.display = 'block';
        return;
      }
      const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
          'name': fileData.name,
          'mimeType': contentType
        };

        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

        //Note: gapi.client.storage.objects.insert() can only insert
        //small objects (under 64k) so to support larger file sizes
        //we're using the generic HTTP request method gapi.client.request()
        var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/storage/v1beta2/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
          'body': multipartRequestBody});
          //Remove the current API result entry in the main-content div
          listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content').childNodes;
          if (listChildren.length > 1) {
            listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
          }
        try{
          //Execute the insert object request
          executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
          //Store the name of the inserted object 
          object = fileData.name;     
        }
        catch(e) {
          alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an Access Control List into
     * your Google Cloud Storage bucket.
     */
    function insertBucketAccessControls() {
      resource = {
        'entity': ENTITY,
        'role': ROLE
      };

      var request = gapi.client.storage.bucketAccessControls.insert({
          'bucket': BUCKET,
          'resource': resource
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'insertBucketAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to insert an Access Control List into
     * your Google Cloud Storage object.
     */
    function insertObjectAccessControls() {
      resource = {
        'entity': ENTITY,
        'role': ROLE_OBJECT
      };

      var request = gapi.client.storage.objectAccessControls.insert({
          'bucket': BUCKET,
          'object': object,
          'resource': resource
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'insertObjectAccessControls');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to delete a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
     */
    function deleteBucket() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.buckets.delete({
          'bucket': BUCKET
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'deleteBucket');
    }

    /**
     * Google Cloud Storage API request to delete a Google Cloud Storage object.
     */
    function deleteObject() {
      var request = gapi.client.storage.objects.delete({
          'bucket': BUCKET,
          'object': object
      });
      executeRequest(request, 'deleteObject');
    }

    /**
     * Removes the current API result entry in the main-content div, adds the
     * results of the entry for your function.
     * @param {string} apiRequestName The name of the example API request.
     */
    function updateApiResultEntry(apiRequestName) {
      listChildren = document.getElementById('main-content')
        .childNodes;
      if (listChildren.length > 1) {
        listChildren[1].parentNode.removeChild(listChildren[1]);
      }
      if (apiRequestName != 'null') {
        window[apiRequestName].apply(this);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Determines which API request has been selected, and makes a call to add
     * its result entry.
     */
    function runSelectedApiRequest() {
      var curElement = document.getElementById('api-selection-options');
      var apiRequestName = curElement.options[curElement.selectedIndex].value;
      updateApiResultEntry(apiRequestName);
    }

    /**
     * Binds event listeners to handle a newly selected API request.
     */
    function addSelectionSwitchingListeners() {
      document.getElementById('api-selection-options')
        .addEventListener('change',
      runSelectedApiRequest, false);
    }

    /**
     * Template for getting JavaScript sample code snippets.
     * @param {string} method The name of the Google Cloud Storage request
     * @param {string} params The parameters passed to method
     */
    function getCodeSnippet(method, params) {
      var objConstruction = "// Declare your parameter object\n";
      objConstruction += "var params = {};";
      objConstruction += "\n\n";

      var param = "// Initialize your parameters \n";
      for (i in params) {
        param += "params['" + i + "'] = ";
        param += JSON.stringify(params[i], null, '\t');
        param += ";";
        param += "\n";
      }
      param += "\n";

      var methodCall = "// Make a request to the Google Cloud Storage API \n";
      methodCall += "var request = gapi.client." + method + "(params);";
      return objConstruction + param + methodCall;
    }


    /**
     * Executes your Google Cloud Storage request object and, subsequently,
     * inserts the response into the page.
     * @param {string} request A Google Cloud Storage request object issued
     *    from the Google Cloud Storage JavaScript client library.
     * @param {string} apiRequestName The name of the example API request.
     */
    function executeRequest(request, apiRequestName) {
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        var apiRequestNode = document.createElement('div');
        apiRequestNode.id = apiRequestName;

        var apiRequestNodeHeader = document.createElement('h2');
        apiRequestNodeHeader.innerHTML = apiRequestName;

        var apiRequestExplanationNode = document.createElement('div');
        apiRequestExplanationNode.id = apiRequestName + 'RequestExplanation';

        var apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader = document.createElement('h3');
        apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader.innerHTML = 'API Request Explanation';
        apiRequestExplanationNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationNodeHeader);

        var apiRequestExplanationEntry = document.createElement('p');
        apiRequestExplanationEntry.innerHTML = 
          listApiRequestExplanations[apiRequestName];
        apiRequestExplanationNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationEntry);

        apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestNodeHeader);
        apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestExplanationNode);

        var apiRequestCodeSnippetNode = document.createElement('div');
        apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.id = apiRequestName + 'CodeSnippet';

        var apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader = document.createElement('h3');
        apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader.innerHTML = 'API Request Code Snippet';
        apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetHeader);

        var apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry = document.createElement('pre');

        //If the selected API command is not 'insertObject', pass the request
        //paramaters to the getCodeSnippet method call as 'request.B.rpcParams'
        //else pass request paramaters as 'request.B' 
        if (apiRequestName != 'insertObject') {
          apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML = 
            getCodeSnippet(request.B.method, request.B.rpcParams);
          //Selected API Command is not 'insertObject'
          //hide insert object button
          filePicker.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML = 
            getCodeSnippet(request.B.method, request.B);
        }
        apiRequestCodeSnippetNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry);
        apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiRequestCodeSnippetNode);

        var apiResponseNode = document.createElement('div');
        apiResponseNode.id = apiRequestName + 'Response';

        var apiResponseHeader = document.createElement('h3');
        apiResponseHeader.innerHTML = 'API Response';
        apiResponseNode.appendChild(apiResponseHeader);

        var apiResponseEntry = document.createElement('pre');
        apiResponseEntry.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(resp, null, ' ');

        apiResponseNode.appendChild(apiResponseEntry);
        apiRequestNode.appendChild(apiResponseNode);

        var content = document.getElementById('main-content');
        content.appendChild(apiRequestNode);
      });
    }

    /**
     * Set required API keys and check authentication status.
     */
    function handleClientLoad() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Authorize Google Cloud Storage API.
     */
    function checkAuth() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: true
      }, handleAuthResult);
    }

    /**
     * Handle authorization.
     */
    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        initializeApi();
    filePicker.onchange = insertObject;
      } else {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      } console.log(gapi.auth);
    }

    /**
     * Handle authorization click event.
     */
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        immediate: false
      }, handleAuthResult);
      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Load Google Cloud Storage API v1beta12.
     */
    function initializeApi() {
      gapi.client.load('storage', API_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Driver for sample application.
     */
    $(window)
      .bind('load', function() {
        gapi.auth.setToken('<?php print $access_token["access_token"]; ?>');
        gapi.auth.token= '<?php print $access_token["access_token"]; ?>';
        console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
        addSelectionSwitchingListeners();
        handleClientLoad();
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    <header>
      <h1>Google Cloud Storage JavaScript Client Library Application</h1>
    </header>
    <label id="api-label">Try a sample API call!</label>
    <select id="api-selection-options">
      <option value="null">
        Please select an example API call from the dropdown menu
      </option>
      <option value="listBuckets">
        List Buckets
      </option>
      <option value="listObjects">
        List Objects
      </option>
      <option value="listBucketsAccessControls">
        List Buckets Access Control List
      </option>
      <option value="listObjectsAccessControls">
        List Objects Access Control List
      </option>
      <option value="getBucket">
        Get Bucket
      </option>
      <option value="getBucketAccessControls">
        Get Bucket Access Controls
      </option>
      <option value="getObjectAccessControls">
        Get Object Access Controls
      </option>
      <option value="insertBucket">
        Insert Bucket
      </option>
      <option value="insertObject">
        Insert Object
      </option>
      <option value="insertBucketAccessControls">
        Insert Bucket Access Controls
      </option>
      <option value="insertObjectAccessControls">
        Insert Object Access Controls
      </option>
      <option value="deleteBucket">
        Delete Bucket
      </option>
      <option value="deleteObject">
        Delete Object
      </option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" id="filePicker" style="display: none" />
    <div id="main-content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm not being successful because my console prints this out:

```
as an error loading the page https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&scope=ht…ifechurch.tv&response_type=token&state=412841043%7C0.2670569503&authuser=0
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to retrieve an access token in your server code for a service account, and then include that as part of a web-page or Javascript response to allow a browser direct access to Google Cloud Storage - this is generally a very dangerous approach, as the access token will allow anyone who has it full access to all of your Cloud Storage resources - without opportunity for your trusted server-side code to be able to apply access control restrictions specific to your application (for example to allow a user of your application only to upload/downloads files/object they should have access to).

Direct file upload/download to Cloud Storage can however be achieved a slightly different way. Google Cloud Storage supports a signed URL - this is a URL that you can generate in your server code (using the same private key you used to get an access token) that allows the bearer the ability to upload or download a specific file for a specific period of time.

Documentation for this can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

And an example from PHP here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/jaRYDWdpteQ/xbNTLfDhUggJ

Once you generate this URL on your server you can pass to the browser, which in turn can then PUT directly to that URL, or GET directly from it without the need to use any special Google Javascript libraries. See for an example: [Google Storage REST PUT With Signed URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611023/google-storage-rest-put-with-signed-urls)

Comment: So I would be able to do a direct image upload using this method?

Comment: Yes! See slides 15-18 of http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io2012/presentations/live%20to%20website/308.pdf for an example.  In that example the server-side part is Python, but the links above show PHP equivalent.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the signature is, and how to generate it. Also, what is this part?'application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded'

Answer (score 0):

I have recently completed a similar project using Ajax to access my PHP class which controls the access token renewals, connection URls etc. As it a live connection over HTTPS no sensitive information is visible in code and I can then load the relevant data directly into javascript.

Hope this helps